# Connect to localhost database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, database

I got a little question about databases and android. I got this code:

```
sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
```

and to read:

```
if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
            int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
            results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    } 
}
```

With this code, I make and read the database, and insert some info in it. And print it on the screen, this all works :)

Now the part I can't figure out:
I use `myPHPadmin (with xampp)`,

I made the exact database as I do in the code.

But how do I connect, so my code reads that database.

It is a local database for now `(127.0.0.1)`.

Is it possible to connect a local database? (if so, could you tell me how to)

Do you need PHP, or can you do everything in (Android) Java code?

I am totally new with databases, so sometimes it confusing for me.

Please put me in the good direction.

If you need more information for the question or something else, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand how you're conflating MySQL and Android? Does your Android app try to access a MySQL DB directly? That sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is a local database for now (`127.0.0.1`).

In Android you have to use `10.0.2.2` or **System's Static IP**.

Write a PHP script (You can also use other but PHP its easy to implement) to manage the database and run this script using HTTP protocol from the android system.

These Tutorials might help you:

- [Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr)
- [Web Services - An XML-RPC Client for Android](http://www.anddev.org/web_services_-_an_xml-rpc_client_for_android-t646.html)

Comment: And also you forget to [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+connecting+sql+databse+from+local+host&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=aXI&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sa=X&ei=i6kPUKPmG8XqrQfDt4HAAQ&ved=0CFcQvwUoAQ&q=android+connecting+sql+database+from+local+host&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=cfdc15839f96c02&biw=1366&bih=664) and this one http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no MySQL library for android. But you can use the HttpPost to send data to a server side script (such as PHP) and then return it in a format you can parse in your Android application.

There's a nice tutorial on how to achieve this here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Here's a link to the HttpPost Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

Hope this helps, this is a good way to get you started communicating with external MySQL databases within an Android application.